# Forgot to put () into function's name but instead of giving an error, it gave me a new value. Any explanation?

Tags: lua

```lua
function Closures()
   local b = 0
   return function() 
      b = b + 1 
      return b 
   end 
end 

bruh = Closures 
print(bruh())
```

The function I showed has a problem: variable *bruh* assigns into `Closures` (I forgot to put () with the variable name). Instead of giving an **error**, it gave me a different result.

> `function: 0056b7f0`

If I add () to the variable name (`Closures`), I would get the result I wanted

> `1`

As I know, `Closures` isn't the function name, but a variable that's assigned to the function. Why do we need () in order to make **return** work? Any explanation? And I can't really get the function "code thing" by returning nothing (It would show nothing if I tried to print a function returned nothing).

**EDIT**: I just figured out that if I do

```
print(Closures())--This and 
print(Closures)
```

I will get some weird function "code":

> function: 0077fa8

> function 0048bc30

P.S.: This syntax error is came accidentally along with the question.

Comment: Functions are first-class values. You can return them from other functions, assign names to them and pass them as arguments to other functions.

Comment: For reference, this is also [in the docs](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Functions are values

I'll use a simpler example to explain:

Say we have a function `func` like this one:

```lua
local func = function() return "REEEEE" end
```

We can assign this function to a new variable like this

```lua
local func2 = func
```

Now `func2` will be a reference to the same function as `func`, so we can call `func2()` and it will return "REEEEE".

When you call `print(Closures)`, you are not executing `Closures`, you are just passing the function itself to `print`, so it calls `tostring` on the function and writes the result to stdout.

When you assign `Closures` to `bruh`, that means `btuh` now holds the same function as `Closures`, and calling it will return the inner function. But try the following:

```lua
bruh = Closures 
print(bruh()())
```

That should print `1`, because calling `bruh` returns a function and calling that then returns the number.